A weighted Edmonds matroid intersection theorem
I am wondering why Theorem 9.4 of this paper this true. (I don't find any proof in the references there.)
To state the theorem, assume $M,N$ are two matroids on $V$. Let $w$ be a weight function $w:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$.
Given a function $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, define a function $f^M$ as a function from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that
$$f^M(x)=\max_{Y\subseteq V:x\in sp_M(Y)}\min_{y\in Y}f(y).$$
Then the theorem says that the maximum weight of a common independent set in both $M$ and $N$, i.e.,
$$\max\{\sum_{x\in I}w(x):I\in M\cap N\},$$
is equal to
$$\min\{\sum_{v\in V}f(v)+g(v): f^M+g^N\ge w\}.$$
It looks something like prime-dual of linear programming, but unclear to me.
